# Eclipse cannot find a library class

Tags: java, android, eclipse, libgdx, classnotfoundexception

I am developing a game in libgdx.
I read the official docs and tried to integrate MobClix Ads in my App but eclipse can found the library that I need. I am trying to resolve this problem but I have no success.
Eclipse cannot resolve this import:

```
import com.mobclix.android.sdk.MobclixMMABannerXLAdView;
```

I tried to replace all my jars an reinstall the sdk and my eclipse is updated.
Somone have also this problem? 
how can I resolve this?

Sorry for my poor english.

Comment: The problem must be that mobclix is not in your classpath.

Comment: Have you added the `mobclix` jar to the project? Do this under the project `properties`/`java build path`/`libraries` and add `mobclix`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try downloading mobclix-4.0.3.jar from http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/m/Downloadmobclix403jar.htm and add it to your Build Path in eclipse. Hopefully, this should resolve your problem